# Stuck at the usage of string library

Tags: c++, c++11

My header file goes like this:

```
//Sales_data.h
#ifndef SALES_DATA_H
#define SALES_DATA_H

//#include<string>

struct Sales_data
{
    std::string bookNo;  //compiles without error
};
#endif
```

Usually, we include the `string` header whenever we have to use string variables in our code.  But the program using the above header compiles without any errors even though I am not including the `string` header in the program.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using precompiled headers. How else would your program know what a `std::string` was? It's not a built-in type. Or, you get lucky and someone else has a `#include<string>` elsewhere. See if you can create a [mcve], with this code. You probably cannot.

Comment: What was the question? How this may seem to "work" ? The translation unit that pulls in `Sales_data.h` has, by some means, previously pulled in `<string>`. And yes, relying on that (the including translation unit fulfilling *your* include dependencies) is not a good plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `include` statement effectively pastes the contents of the included file into the including file. This builds one massive file that combines the source file and all of the included headers. This combined file is ultimately what is compiled.

Lets add a simple driver to the header to demonstrate how this can work:

```
#include <string>
#include "sales_data.h"
int main()
{

}
```

becomes

```
#include <string> // actual contents of string omitted for brevity
#ifndef SALES_DATA_H
#define SALES_DATA_H

//#include<string>

struct Sales_data
{
    std::string bookNo;  //compiles without error
};
#endif

int main()
{

}
```

and this will compile, but it relies on an external dependency: `<string>` must be included ahead of `"sales_data.h"`. This means one slight change

```
#include "sales_data.h"
#include <string>
int main()
{

}
```

And your goose is cooked. Worse, perhaps

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sales_data.h"
int main()
{

}
```

compiles just fine because `<iostream>` includes `<string>` under compiler X's standard library implementation. Perhaps compiler Y's library does not and produces an error message saying `std::string` is missing. Worse, Compiler Z's designers decided there was a measurable optimization to be gained by forward declaring `std::string` instead of including `<string>` and the forward declaration is not enough to fully satisfy `"sales_data.h"`. Compiler Z may spit out an utterly bizarre error message because `std::string` exists, but is incomplete and cannot be used to declare `bookNo`.

The includer of this header must know ahead of time that `<string>` must be included or face some irritating debugging just to compile their code. This isn't a fair expectation to drop on anyone, especially when the solution is so utterly trivial.

As a result, convention and best practice is to ensure that all headers are internally self-consistent. The header **SHOULD** be able to stand alone and compile with a minimal driver. If the following will not compile

```
#include "header_under_test.h"
int main()
{

}
```

`"header_under_test.h"` is not complete and **SHOULD** be completed before being exposed to the wild. The time and frustration you save could be your own.

Answer (score 2):

This is a function of your specific compiler/implementation of the standard library. Generally speaking, to make your code 100% portable, you should include the `string` header, because not every compiler will do this. I know that current versions of both `gcc` and `clang` allow it (I'm uncertain about MSVC), but in order to make your code standards-compliant, you should always include the `string` header where you want to use `std::string`. If you ever find yourself having to develop for a platform where the compiler doesn't do this, the code you've given above will fail to compile and you'll have to spend time and effort debugging it. So why bother? Toss in that `#include <string>`, keep programming, and save yourself the trouble of fixing it later.